# Conflict results inside our search's "Managed Properties" & "Crawled Properties" sections

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, administration, managed-property, crawled-property

I have a site column of type Choice named "Topics", and i want to  check if SharePoint  Online has created "Managed Properties" & "Crawled Properties" for the site column.

From admin center site >> search >> search schema >> Managed Property >> i can see that there is a managed property created but not mapped to any crawled property, as follow:-

[image]

while if i go to the Crawled Properties section, i can see that the crawl property is mapped to the above managed property as follow:-

[image]

so why i am getting conflict results? could this be a bug in the UI? or i have something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a test in my SharePoint online and i can reproduce your issue.

For this issue, i suggest you create a service request.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/